# MySQL UPDATE с SELECT SUM из другой таблицы

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Есть две таблицы **'orders' *(id, bank_name, order_amount)*** и **'balances' *(bank_name, total_balance)***. С помощью формы данные добавляются в таблицу **'orders'** и в тоже время обновляется значение ***total_balance*** в **'balances'** в зависимости от ***bank_name***.

Существует также форма для того чтобы изменять какое-то значение в таблице **'orders'**. Все это прекрасно работает.

Если при помощи второй формы изменять значение ***order_amount*** в таблице **'orders'**, то значение ***total_balance*** в таблице **'balances'** также должно меняться. Для этого я хочу сделать следующее:

При изменении ***order_amount*** в таблице **'orders'**, с помощью SUM() должно подсчитываться общая сумма всех ***order_amount*** в зависимости от  ***bank_name*** и обновляться знание ***total_balance*** в таблице **'balances'**.

То есть, изменяем стоку в таблице **'orders'**, суммируем ***order_amount*** и обновляем значение ***total_balance*** в **'balances'**:

```
$result1 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ".$orders." SET `bank_name` = '$bank_name', `order_amount` = '$order_amount' where id = '$id'");

$result2 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ".$balance." SET `total_balance` = (SELECT SUM(order_amount) AS order_amount FROM ".$orders." GROUP by bank_name) WHERE bank_name = '$bank_name'");
```

`$result1` работает, но `$result2` к сожалению нет.. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, не работает, потому что

```
SELECT SUM(order_amount) AS order_amount FROM ".$orders." GROUP by bank_name
```

выбирект несколько строк, а вам нужна одна. Нужно как минимум добавить

```
WHERE bank_name = '$bank_name'
```

к селекту.

А все записи можно обновить так -

```
UPDATE `".$balance."` as `b`
JOIN (SELECT SUM(`order_amount`) AS `order_amount`, `bank_name` FROM `".$orders."` GROUP by `bank_name`) as `o` ON `b`.`bank_name` = `o`.`bank_name`
SET `b`.`total_balance` = `o`.`order_amount`;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!